# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, openai-api, gpt-3

Just experimenting with OpenAI's api and have a very basic express app up and running. What I'm trying to do is just get it to send me back an appropriate response with a basic input but it currently keeps failing.

I'm using Postman to iterate on the code on localhost. All packages are definitely installed and the API key is correct and specfied in the .env file.

My current working file is below. I'm sure I'll kick myself but can anyone spot what dumb thing I've probably done?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const axios = require('axios'); // Come back to this

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

app.get('/api/v1', async (req, res) => {
    
  let body = {
      model: "text-davinci-003",        
      prompt: "How are you?",
      temperature: 1,
      max_tokens: 2086,
      top_p: 1,
      frequency_penalty: 0,
      presence_penalty: 0,
  };

  
  const response = await openai.createCompletion(body);

  res.send({ response });
});

// Listen for requests
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

**Error generated in terminal**

```
/home/mint-pc/Desktop/projects/ebooks/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1150
    : JSON.stringify(value);
           ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/home/mint-pc/Desktop/projects/ebooks/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1150:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/mint-pc/Desktop/projects/ebooks/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:271:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/mint-pc/Desktop/projects/ebooks/api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:162:21)
    at /home/mint-pc/Desktop/projects/ebooks/api/ghost_writer.js:48:7
```

Comment: Inspect the `response` object. It's likely a complete HTTP response object and not just the response data. This explains the error you're getting, since the complete response object would indeed contain the original request object. Such objects are usually fairly large and deeply nested, making them unsuitable for JSON serialization as the error suggests.

Comment: @Boaz

Legend, that was it thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### STEP 1: Run Express server

Run `nodemon test.js` in the terminal.

**test.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const { OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const openai = new OpenAIApi();

app.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const request_options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer xxxxx`
            },
            body: {
                model: req.body.model,
                prompt: req.body.prompt,
                max_tokens: 7,
                temperature: 0
            }
        }

        openai.createCompletion(request_options)
            .then((response) => {
                res.send({ response });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);
            })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

#### STEP 2: Provide `model` and `prompt` parameters in request body

```
{
  "model": "text-davinci-003",
  "prompt": "Say this is a test"
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Parameters]

**Also, don't forget to provide your API key!**

Screenshot:

[image: API key]

#### STEP 3: Click "Send" to make an HTTP POST request

You should get `200 OK` and the following response:

```
{
  "id": "cmpl-6ZNYkREx9KEThpq2keFD9E1Xic3q6",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "created": 1673890062,
  "model": "text-davinci-003",
  "choices": [
    {
      "text": "\n\nThis is indeed a test.",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 5,
    "completion_tokens": 8,
    "total_tokens": 13
  }
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that app.post was my defined app route for users to visit and is therefore arbitrary?

Incidentally, I did try your suggestion, continued to receive the same error

Comment: This answer runs the risk of causing the same issue the OP has mentioned. The `response` object seems to be different than what the OP gets. Perhaps focus on that?

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75136962/express-app-and-openai-api-createcompletion-method-not-working/75137250#comment132592364_75136962) by @Boaz: "Inspect the response object. It's likely a complete HTTP response object and not just the response data..."

It was that.

I was trying to access the response data in a syntactically incorrect way because the response data was nested inside a larger response object.

Comment: Can you provide more context? when does it happen, and why?